# In AngularJs, how to add/remove $resource items to/from the cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I have a $resource, which I am using for fetching one or all Registrations, creating new or update existing Registrations, deleting registrations... the works. Here's the code of the resource:

```
    .factory('Registrations', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/registrations/:assetType/:registrationId',
            {assetType: '@assetType', registrationId: '@assetRegistrationId'},
            {query: {
                method: 'GET',
                cache: true,
                isArray: true
            }}
        );
    })
```

As you can see, caching is put in place, and this works fine: subsequent requests aren't propagated to the server. Except... after the creation or the removal of a Registration, the cache isn't updated.

For the removal I have come up with this workaround. It looks terrible but it works. There's some strange things to notice though:

```
        Registrations.delete({assetType: $scope.assetType, registrationId: registration.assetRegistrationId}, function () {

            //doesn't seem to work -> dirty hack
            //$cacheFactory.get('$http').remove('api/registrations/' + $scope.assetType + '/' + registration.registrationId);
            var cached = $cacheFactory.get('$http').get('api/registrations/' + $scope.assetType);
            var cachedRegistrations = JSON.parse(cached[1]);
            var registrationInCache = get(cachedRegistrations, registration.assetRegistrationId);
            if (registrationInCache) {
                cachedRegistrations.splice(cachedRegistrations.indexOf(registrationInCache), 1);
                cached[1] = JSON.stringify(cachedRegistrations);
            }

            $scope.registrations = Registrations.query({assetType: $scope.assetType});

            //...
```

The surprising thing is that the cache doesn't keep a list of javascript objects, but just 1 entry with a an actual string representing the json of all items. What I'm doing is then jsonifying that string, removing the deleted item and stringifying the list again.

For the creation I haven't been that creative, and I can only remove that one entry (representing the complete collection) in the cache and reload all the data from the server. Here's how I invalidate the cache.

```
$cacheFactory.get('$http').remove('api/registrations/' + $scope.assetType);
```

I'm probably missing something obvious. Anybody any suggestions or clarifications? Thanks!

Comment: So if you're not communicating to the server, why do you need to use `cache`?

Comment: Where does it say I am not communicating with a server? I just want an easy way to update my client $cache after I have added/removed an item. Actually I would think angular's $resource would do this for me.

Comment: "But I'm changing this data on the client - no roundtrip to the server should be necessary." Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question but why do you need cache? Can't you just update your client object?

Comment: If I don't enable my $resource's cache, every time I load my page, the data will be fetched from the server.

Comment: Right, but as I said, Angular has no way of knowing when the data in your server has changed and will therefore keep getting the results from cache. This why I recommend using cache on the server side. That way you still make requests to your server, but your server is a lot faster at giving it back if it hasn't changed. What you attempted may work in theory but I think you're overcomplicating things on the client side.

Comment: Another alternative would be to make the original request, store the result in the client (not in cache) and modify/work with that object and only save it to the server when you need to.

Comment: OK, I thought if I save an item via $resource and I send back the created item, angular could be smart enough to update its cache with that item. Or provide a simple means to let me update that cache.

Comment: As far as I understand `$resource`'s cache is useful if you always expect to get the same results from your requests so that when you run to the function again it doesn't make another server request. This is not the case in your scenario. You seem to have found a way around that, but IMHO, it's unnecessary and won't actually improve your performance.

Comment: I could be wrong though, go over the docs just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this kind of caching should be done on the server side, not on the front-end (AngularJS). I'm not 100% sure how Angular's `cache=true` work but I believe it just caches the result so additional requests will get the cached results. Angular can't tell when the data on your server has changed.

Comment: But I'm changing this data on the client - no roundtrip to the server should be necessary.

Comment: Right, so why do you need cache? If it's already on the client (like the the Angular cache is) then it should be pretty fast or at least as fast as loading from cache.

Comment: My point is in both cases you're loading something that's already in your client so there's no need to use cache.